# Rescaling iFrame content works in Chrome - NOT other browsers - any Solutions?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Rescaling iFrame content works in Chrome, but not other browsers. Any solutions? I'd like a cross-browser solution for rescaling an iframe to place a form in.

It doesn't rescale in IE8 and Firefox 15.0.1. It appears at 100% in these browsers, but is reduced in Chrome. Any thoughts?

```
<iframe src="http://www.apple.com/"
frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no"
width="66%" margin: 0 auto; align= "left "seamless="seamless"style="
-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);
width: 400px; height: 400px;"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DisEngaged/t9yhm/

Comment: You should close your opening `<iframe>` tag here:  `400px;"</iframe>`

Comment: Closed tag, but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a small typo / used the wrong syntax for Firefox. You have used a `-` instead of a `:`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/t9yhm/3/

**Instead of:**

```
-moz-transform-scale(0.5);
```

**It should be:**

```
-moz-transform:scale(0.5);
```

Also, it is worth noting that the latest versions of Firefox support the unprefixed version:

```
transform:scale(0.5);
```

**EDIT :**

Sorry, I've just noticed that you wanted a "cross-browser" solution. The CSS3 below will support the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE9+ :

```
iframe{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

For IE8 and below there is a filter you can use, but it has a complicated syntax:

```
/* IE8+ - must be on one line*/ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
        M11=0.5,
        M12=0,
        M21=0,
        M22=0.5,
        SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

To help you calculate the matrix values you can use this site: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/